# How to remove google map markers when using angular-google-maps directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-google-maps

So I'm having a problem removing the markers from my page when using angular-google-maps.
here is the haml:

```
    %div.map-view
      %ui-gmap-google-map{control:"controller.map.control", center: "controller.map.center", zoom: "controller.map.zoom", options: "controller.mapOptions"}
        %ui-gmap-markers{control:"controller.markers", models: "controller.points", idkey: "'location_id'", coords: "'self'", icon: "'icon'", fit: "true", click: "'onClicked'"}
```

and then in my controller:

```
deleteMarkers: () =>
  if(@markers.getGMarkers().length != [].length)
    @markers.removeMany(@markers.getGMarkers())
```

That last line doesn't work because the removeMany method doesn't appear to be exposed on the control and I get this error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I was having a similar problem and was unable to find a solution. Finally, I got around it by hiding my markers. Not sure if that would help in your situation though, but just in case: you can hide the markers by setting **visible** to "false" in the [options](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) object.

Comment: Thanks rtorres - in the end i got around this by introducing a counter in my controller and using it to set the ids on each of the new markers. Hopefully they'll fix this soon.